# Changing position of prices in Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I just started using Woocommerce, and one of the things i'd like is to change the position of the old price and the new, discounted price. What I have now is that you first see the old price and then the discounted price. I would really appreciate it if you could help me fix this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/**
 *
 * Code used to change the price order in WooCommerce
 *
 * */
function mycustom_woocommerce_price_html($price, $product) {
    return preg_replace('@(<del>.*?</del>).*?(<ins>.*?</ins>)@misx', '$2 $1', $price);
}

add_filter('woocommerce_get_price_html', 'mycustom_woocommerce_price_html', 100, 2);
```

Please put this code in your active theme's functions.php